# Could someone explain to me what is the importance of using the sleep method of the Thread class in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am struggling to understand why every time I use threads in java i have call the .sleep() method first. I would like someone to explain to me why is it useful to call the sleep method.
And what could happen if it is not called.

Comment: Why do you think that? You don't ever have to call sleep().

Comment: I "assume" you might call `Thread.sleep` because someone is waiting for the `Thread` to start (either the `Thread` that was started or the `Thread` that started it).  A lock of some kind might be a more suitable solution, but you've provided next to no context for the question

Answer (score 4):

Thread.sleep causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period. This is an efficient means of making processor time available to the other threads of an application or other applications that might be running on a computer system. The sleep method can also be used for pacing, as shown in the example that follows, and waiting for another thread with duties that are understood to have time requirements, as with the SimpleThreads example in a later section.

For more information, please refer to this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Answer (score 0):

Sleep is used to pause the thread for x number of milliseconds, as specified in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)